# eBay webhook option is available?

Tags: api, webhooks, ebay-api

I am new to eBay API. How do I trigger the eBay API call, when new order is created. Is there any webhooks function exist? I want to get the new order details, when created. In eBay documentation doesn't tell about hooks. Some other forums said use Client Alert api/ Trading api. Is it useful to get trigger when order is created. Please explain how can i get those order details.

Answer (score 2):

Although I've never used these APIs it looks like there's two avenues for you to investigate.

1. [Platform Notifications](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/guides/features-guide/default.html#Notifications/Notifications.html)
2. [Client Alerts](https://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/client-alerts/docs/Concepts/ClientAlertsAPIGuide.html)

My bet is on Platform Notifications to be the thing you're looking for. Both of these APIs are part of the "Traditional" APIs, that is, they're the older APIs.